# How do I display Duplicate values in a map to be displayed as a List Item when pushing parsed JSON into map using Java . Map<String, Set String>

Tags: java, android, json

I have two different "ideas" that share the same url I need both urls to be displayed  currently I am only able to see one of the duplicated urls . How can I set them separately to be called specialty resulting in both urls being displayed ?
Also , I am parsing this Data from a static Json Page and I know using Set filters duplicates so I would like to make this call to each item separately because I have to use Set in this task

Thanks for any help !

```
public String loadJSON() {
    String json = null;

    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("parse.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int image[] = {R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2, R.drawable.3,
        R.drawable.4, R.drawable.5, R.drawable.6};

    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(loadJSON());
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("gig");

        for (int i =0; i <array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj_inside = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String idea = obj_inside.getString("id");
            JSONArray contents = obj_inside.getJSONArray("cont");

            for (int j =0; j < contents.length(); j++) {
                int ran_image = image[((int) (image.length * Math.random()))];
                JSONObject jsonObject = contents.getJSONObject(j);
                String contT = jsonObject.getString("contT");
                String campU = jsonObject.getString("campU");

                Map<String,Collection<String>> map=new HashMap<String,             Collection<String>>();
            Set<String> url = new HashSet<String>();
            url.add(campU);
            map.put(idea, url);
            System.out.println(map.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using Set, why not List?

Comment: These are the requirement that were given to me , can I use list and still use the set up of Map<String, Set String>?

Comment: No, you can not add List<String> object in Map<String, Set<String>>.  According to me in your case, collections are used for the sake of json conversion. Though Set<String> represents JsonArray, List<String> is also corresponds to JsonArray so I think you should use List<String> if its not hampering anything else

Comment: I would love to use List<String> instead of Set<String> but when I do it causes the entire program to attempt a migration of pre written code which has already been declared as such. Thanks for your help though , if you think of any way that this can be achieved it would be very valuable to me :-)

Comment: I just tried it and it gave me an error because I am setting the url in a position where i have already declared it as Set<String> and when I cast it gives me a cast exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Answer (score 0):

can you try using `Map<String,Collection<String>>`

```
         Map<String,Collection<String>> map=new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
         List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
         url.add(new String("str1"));
         url.add(new String("str1"));
         map.put("", url);
```

So that you will have flexibility to put List or Set as value in the map

Comment: I think this may work , but How would I set this map to my list Items , I have a list displayed as such ListItem li = new ListItem();
                li = new ListItem();
                li.name = contT;
                li.image = ran_image;
                li.url = campU;
                listItems.put(li.url, li);
                url.add(li.url);                                                                                            On display it is still eliminating the duplicate value.

Comment: Would you show me in code , Its giving me an exception,  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set

Comment: use Map<String,Collection<String>> instead of Map<String,Set<String>>

Comment: Map<String,Collection<String>> map=new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
                Set<String> url = new HashSet<String>();
                url.add(campU);
                map.put(idea, url);
                System.out.println(map.toString());                                                            This is how I have it , when I use list instead ofSet it causes an exception .I am setting url in a position where I have already declared it Set<String>